# How can I replace my select with new Linq syntax and add in a Regex?

Tags: c#

I am using the following code:

```
var valuesWithNames = from value in values1
   select new { 
      Value = (int)value.ToString("00"), 
      Text = value.ToString() 
  };
```

How I can I change this to use the new Linq syntax and also
change it so that the Text that I return has the following
Regex applied to it ?

```
".Select(n => Regex.Replace(n, "([A-Z])", " $1").Trim());"
```

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic I believe the OP means using the fluent methods rather than the query syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var valuesWithNames = from value in values1
    select new { 
        Value = (int)value.ToString("00"), 
        Text = value.ToString() 
    };
```

Is equivalent to:

```
var valuesWithNames = values1.Select
(
    value => new
    {
        Value = (int)value.ToString("00"),
        Text = value.ToString() 
    }
);
```

You can initialise Text with any expression that returns a `string`, so for your regex you should just be able to use:

```
var valuesWithNames = values1.Select
(
    value => new
    {
        Value = int.Parse(value.ToString("00")),
        Text = Regex.Replace(value.ToString(), "([A-Z])", " $1").Trim()
    }
);
```

Comment: This is giving me an error: Error 8 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(string, string, string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Also on the Value = line :  Error 7 Cannot convert type 'string' to 'int'

Comment: @SamanthaJ If `value` is not a string you will need to use `value.ToString()`. Also I didn't even look at the `Value =` line I just copied what you already had. Now that I look at it it doesn't make much sense... You can't cast `string` to `int` you have to use `int.Parse()`, but calling `ToString()` and then `Parse()` immediately afterwards is very odd. What are you trying to do on that line?

Answer (score 1):

The code should like this :

```
var valuesWithNames = from value in values1
select new { 
    Value = (int)value.ToString("00"), 
    Text =  Regex.Replace(value.ToString(), "([A-Z])", " $1").Trim() 
};
```